# How to refresh a view content?

Tags: java, android

I wanna create a program has two `Button`s named `button1` and `button2`.This is block of `button1` `onClick` method :

```
    public void click1(View v){
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b.setText("TEXT 1");
        SystemClock.sleep(500);
        b.setText("TEXT 2");

    }
```

but the problem is after first change of object 'b' text to "TEXT 1" , it occurs nothing and after 500 ms text of 'b' changes to "TEXT 2".

What's the problem?

How to refresh `Layout` views contents?

Comment: `SystemClock.sleep(500);` Remove this line

Comment: I need this line.Instead of this line it will come a heavy code, I need that for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `SystemClock.sleep(500);`, please you `Handler`, you can try this code:

```
public void click1(View v){
                Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
                b.setText("TEXT 1");
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        b.setText("TEXT 2");    
                    }
                }, 500;)
                //b.forceLayout();
            }
```

Hope this helps.